# Show $\varepsilon > 0$ and strictly increasing seq of indices $\{n_k\}$ s.t. $k$, $\vert f(s_{n_k}) - f(t_{n_k}) \vert\ge \varepsilon$

Tags: real-analysis

This is a question from Advanced Calculus, Fitzpatrick. Section 3.4 Q12

> Suppose that the function $f : D \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is not uniformly continuous. Then by definition there are sequences $\{s_n\}$ and $\{t_n\}$ in $D$ such that $$\lim_\limits{n \to \infty}[s_n - t_n] = 0 \text{, but } \lim_\limits{n \to \infty}[f(s_n) - f(t_n)] \neq 0$$
> **A.** Show that there is an $\epsilon > 0$ and a strictly increasing sequence of indices $\{n_k\}$ such that for each index $k$, $\vert f(s_{n_k}) - f(t_{n_k}) \vert \geq \varepsilon$

**My attempt**
\begin{align}
\lim_\limits{n \to \infty}[f(s_n) - f(t_n)] \neq 0 && \tag{1}\\
\neg (\forall \varepsilon > 0, \exists N \text{ s.t. } \forall n \geq N \; \vert f(s_n)-f(t_n)\vert < \varepsilon) && \text{logical definition}\tag{2}\\
\exists \epsilon \gt 0, \forall N, \exists k \geq N \; \vert f(s_k)-f(t_k)\vert \geq \varepsilon && \text{apply negation throughout}\tag{3}
\end{align}

I'm stuck here. It seems like this would define a subsequence $\{n_k\}$ but I don't think it's necessarily strictly increasing.

For example, we could have a sequence $N = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]$

For $N=1, k=3$ --> $N_k = [3]$
For $N=2, k=2$ --> $N_k = [3, 2]$
For $N=3, k=5$ --> $N_k = [3, 2, 5]$ .... etc

**Question**
Is this a reasonable way to approach this problem? Are there any errors in my first 3 arguments?

Comment: Hint: at each stage, use the previous $k$ in place of $N$

Comment: Prove that if there doesn't exist such a increasing sequence $\{n_{k} \}$ then $f$ is uniformly continuous which is a contradiction.Hope it helps. Your approach is not bad though.

Comment: Ah @Peanut yes that makes sense, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this directly. Set $c_n=|f(s_n) - f(t_n)|.$ Then you know that $\lim_\limits{n \to \infty}c_n \neq 0.$ This means that $\overline {\lim}c_n$ is different from zero. (why?). If it is infinite, the result follows trivially. If $\overline {\lim}c_n=c>0$ then write $\overline {\lim}c_n=\underset{k\to \infty}\lim \sup_{k\le n}c_n=\underset{k\to \infty}\lim g_k=c.$

Each $g_k\ge c.$ Let $K$ be large enough so that $k\ge K\Rightarrow |g_k-c|<c/4.$ Thus, this inequality is satisfied for the subsequence $\{g_K,\ g_{K+1},\cdots ,\}$, which we relabel $\{g_1,\ g_{2},\cdots ,\}$ for convenience.

Using the definition of the supremum, we find an integer $k_1$ such that $g_1-c_{k_1}<c/4;\ k_1\ge 1.$ And an integer $k_2$ such that $g_{k_1+1}-c_{k_2}<c/4;\ k_2>k_1$ (by construction). Inductively, we obtain a sequence $(c_{k_j})$ that satifies

$|c_{k_j}-c|\le |c_{k_j}-g_{k_j+1}|+|g_{k_j+1}-c|\le c/4+c/4=c/2\Rightarrow c_{k_j}>c/2$ so the claim follows with $\epsilon=c/2.$